# Are the proofs of Caratheodory's extension theorem and Caratheodory's lemma typically included in a graduate probability class?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

By graduate probability class I mean the typical "Probability I" required by statistics PhD programs.

Both Caratheodory's extension theorem and Caratheodory's lemma are crucial for the construction of probability spaces. However, as stated in Williams' Probability With Martingales, page 20: "once we have our model, we have no use of the theorem", it seems to me that there are no significant use of both theorems in the later part of such class. In Amir Dembo's notes on probability theory, he also stated Caratheodory's extension theorem without a proof.

If the proofs are omitted, more time can be used on topics like weak convergence. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHB, I don't like teachers including Caratheodory's theorem in their teaching. The reason is pretty the same as yours. It seems to me that the professors - who like incorporating the demonstration of that theorem in their syllabus - are more or less old-school.

Comment: For your information, within my limited knowledge, in some schools,  Caratheodory's theorem is a compulsory topic in a second-year (undergraduate) probability course.

Comment: P/s: It's highly likely that your topic will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what one wants out of that education. For either pure or applied statistical work you don't need it. But if you are likely to need to do some heavy probability theory then it is useful to have a good understanding of the measure theoretic background. It likely isn't necessary to teach it in a statistics program but it is much more important in a mathematics program.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It's likely I will encounter continuous time stochastic processes sometime later, does that count as heavy probability theory?

Comment: You could certainly get by without seeing the proof of this theorem. But why fight it so hard? Anyone dealing with continuous time srochastic processes is clearly into serious math. The details of the theorem should hardly be scary to you.